# CSP issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, content-security-policy

We are facing issue while exporting documents from our portal which is embedded into an iframe of some external portal.

We see the following error in the console :

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob:https://abc.def.com/1gg3810-ae25-42ae-ghghb-123456789 (“frame-src”).

This issue comes only in firefox. We are able to export documents in other browsers. We think that the problem comes due to the portal is embedded into an iframe. when we execute the download URL in a separate tab, it allows to download the document.

We are using below CSP policy :

default-src * blob: 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data:; img-src * data:; frame-src * blob: data: 'self'; object-src *

Thanks

Comment: At that point, why are you even using CSP at all? You might as well turn if off entirely if you're not actually going to rely on it to keep things secure. The value in CSP is from _not_ allowing things like eval and blob, because _you cannot control those_ so you shouldn't be allowing those.

Comment: The CSP is set by external portal where we have no control. Our application is just shown in an iframe in that portal.

Comment: Then someone needs to contact your portal admins: as is, a CSP that permissive does borderline nothing. Having said that, the blob you're showing is not a blob at all, it's a regular URL with `blob:` added in front of it, so the first thing to try would be to just remove the `blob:` prefix and see if things now work.

Comment: The URL is generated by Firefox when reporting the error. Harish is generating the blob in a client side script and then trying to trigger a download. This is common when you already have data on the client in a table/chart and want a button a 'download-as-CSV' etc. button. Firefox interprets CSP differently meaning this will fail if `frame-src` doesn't include `bind:`. Unfortunately it's often not possible to change the parent's CSP. You can work around this with a hidden i-frame [as discussed here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-bridge/issues/11).

Answer (score 3):

I also face this issue when exporting the image in the iframe,usually we export the image by creating a a tag in the document`document.createElement('a')`,now in order to solve this issue,you need to change the code like `window.top.document.createElement("a")`,hope it is useful for you.